# Logical operators in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create program in which user pass two values and logical operator, for example `1, 3, <=`. The answer should be `True` but I don't know how can I handle it in Python since the `"<"` is a string  not `<`.

Comment: you can use `result = eval(f"{val1} {operator} {val2}")` or conditionals `if operator == "<=":  result = val1 <= val2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `operator` lib in python. Try this:

```py
import operator


operators = {
    ">": operator.gt,
    ">=": operator.ge,
    "<": operator.lt,
    "<=": operator.le,
    "==": operator.eq,
    "!=": operator.ne
}


def eval_compare(value1: str, value2: str, op: str) -> bool:
    return operators[op](int(value1), int(value2))


# try
print(eval_compare("2", "3", "<"))
```